# Counterexample to proposition on $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, independence

> If $\sigma$-algebras $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{G}$ are independent
>   and if sigma-algebras $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{H}$ are independent
>   then $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr I := \sigma(\mathscr{G},\mathscr{H})$ are
>   independent.

What is a counterexample to this?

If $\sigma$-algebras $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{G}$ are independent, then

$\forall F \in \mathscr{F}, G \in \mathscr{G}$,

$$P(F \cap G) = P(F)P(G)$$

If $\sigma$-algebras $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{H}$ are independent, then

$\forall F \in \mathscr{F}, H \in \mathscr{H}$,

$$P(F \cap H) = P(F)P(H)$$

So I need an $I \in \mathscr I$ s.t.

$$P(F \cap I) = P(F)P(I)$$

Comment: Do you know an example of three events (in some probability space) that are pairwise independent but not mutually independent?

Comment: @JohnDawkins [Yes?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Pairwise_and_mutual_independence) Thinking now...

Comment: @JohnDawkins Oh I forgot that we can infer G and H are independent. Thanks! How about now?

Comment: NO, you can't infer that $\mathscr G$ and $\mathscr H$ are independent.

Comment: @JohnDawkins [Damn it!](http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~brani/isyebayes/bank/handout1.pdf) Okay so what then?

Comment: For a counterexample, I was suggesting that you find three events $A,B,C$ (in some probability space) that are pairwise independent but not mutually independent. Then take $\mathscr F=\sigma(A), \mathscr G=\sigma(B), \mathscr H = \sigma (C)$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thanks. Thinking further...

Comment: @JohnDawkins How about now?

Comment: Remember this is to be a counterexample, so you want $P(A)P(I)\not= P(A\cap I)$. Also, review the definition of "mutually independent". Also, what's your example of $A,B,C$?

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thanks! Edited. Why do I need to review that definition? What do you mean what is my example? A, B and C are events in the probability space. For a concrete example, there's [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Pairwise_and_mutual_independence), I guess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31068/discussion-between-john-dawkins-and-bclc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$, events A, B and C, pairwise independent but not mutually independent.

Then

$$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$$

$$P(A \cap C) = P(A)P(C)$$

$$P(C \cap B) = P(C)P(B)$$

$$P(A \cap C \cap B) \ne P(A)P(C)P(B)$$

Let:

$$\mathscr F = \sigma(A)$$

$$\mathscr G = \sigma(B)$$

and $\mathscr H = \sigma(C)$

Then $\mathscr I = \sigma(B, C)$.

$\mathscr F = \sigma(A)$ and $\mathscr G = \sigma(B)$ are independent.

$\mathscr F = \sigma(A)$ and $\mathscr H = \sigma(C)$ are independent.

We must show that $\mathscr F = \sigma(A)$ and $\mathscr I = \sigma(B, C)$ are not independent i.e. $\exists I \in \mathscr I$ s.t.

$$P(A)P(I) \ne P(A \cap I)$$

Now choose $I = B \cap C$ which works because $\mathscr G = \sigma(B)$ and $\mathscr H = \sigma(C)$ are independent.